# Trouble with Unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand the basic idea of a union of two sets as the set containing the elements belonging to a or b, where a and b are arbitrary members. I'm stuck with this new definition of union as applying to only set, and following questions. In a slide I was given the definition:

$\cup A = \{x \;|\; \exists b \in A \mbox{ and } x \in b \}$

and following questions:

Find sets $A$, $B$ such that $A \not= B$, but $\cup A = \cup B$
Show that every member of $A$ is a subset of $\cup A$

We are not using atoms in our course, so sets will be built up out of other sets. I would greatly appreciate someone telling me what I'm missing and how to approach these sorts of questions.

Comment: Your "union of two sets" $A$ and $B$ is, in this notation, $$\cup \{A, B \}$$
Does that help?

Comment: There are two distinct operators employing the "$cup$" notation. The **binary** operator joins two sets (as in "$A\cup B$"). By abuse of notation, you can chain it over several sets, such as with "$A\cup B \cup C\cup D$". If you have too many to write down explicitly, group the sets into a single collection (still separate, just boxed up), and apply the **unary operator** to join all of the sets in the collection together at once; for example write $W=\{A,B,C,D\}$, so $\cup W = A\cup B \cup C\cup D$.

Comment: In set theory, you are not allowed to define a set only by a property. $\{x \mid \exists b \in A \land x \in b \}$ is hence not permitted. This notation allows to describe Russel's paradox, which produces an inconsistent theory. You only can do this with objects already in a set: $\{x\mathbf{\in A}\mid P(x)\}$. When thinking about set theory it is always helpful to remember that everything is a set. So the elements of a set are sets that also contains elements. $A \cup B$ is obtained using the axiom of union and the axiom of pairing together. It is just a notation for $\cup\{A, B\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $A=\big\{\{0,1\}\big\}$ and $B=\big\{\{0\},\{1\}\big\}$, for instance, where $0=\varnothing$ and $1=\{0\}$. By definition $x\in\bigcup A$ if and only if $x\in y$ for some $y\in A$, and the only $y\in A$ is $y=\{0,1\}$, so $x\in\bigcup A$ if and only if $x\in\{0,1\}$. Thus, $\bigcup A=\{0,1\}$.

Similarly, $x\in\bigcup B$ if and only if $x\in y$ for some $y\in B$. The possible values of $y$ are $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$, so $x\in\bigcup B$ if and only if $x\in\{0\}$ or $x\in\{1\}$. But that’s simply saying that $x\in\bigcup B$ if and only if $x\in\{0\}\cup\{1\}=\{0,1\}$, so $\bigcup B=\{0,1\}=\bigcup A$, even though it’s clear that $A\ne B$.

I’ll stop at this point for now; see if the example clarifies the situation enough to let you approach the general result that if $y\in A$, then $y\subseteq\bigcup A$. Remember, so show that $y\subseteq\bigcup A$ you must simply show that if $x\in y$, then $x\in\bigcup A$.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, pick you're favorite set and split it up two different ways:

$X = \{1,2,3,4,5\} = \{1,2\} \cup \{3,4,5\}$ vs. $\{1,2,3,4\} \cup \{5\}$

If you let $A = \{ \{1,2\}, \{3,4,5\} \}$, then $\cup A = X$. Likewise, if $B = \{ \{1,2,3,4\}, \{5\}\}$, then $\cup B = X$. So $\cup A=\cup B$, but clearly $A \not= B$.

For your second question, to show something is a subset of something else, you need to take every element of the first set and show that it belongs to the second set.

So take some member of $A$, say $S$. Then you need to show $x \in S$ implies that $x \in \cup A$. This just amounts to unraveling the definition of "$\cup A$".

I hope this gets you started! :)